# Are there any methods to figure out how aerodynamic a race car is without a Cd number?

Tags: power, aerodynamics

For the top speed of a car, I believe it's usually limited by drag and horsepower. However, I've also learned that gearing can affect the top speed and acceleration of a car. Are there any methods to figuring out how much more aerodynamic one car is to another only using speed and power? I know this sounds unclear so I'll provide an example: The 2009 Corvette C6.R has 590 hp and can reach 200 mph. The 2008 Aston Martin DBR9 has 600 hp and can reach 180 mph. If you give the C6.R 600 hp, its new theoretical top speed would be 201.1 mph. Does mean that it is more aerodynamic, or is there more to it?

Comment: Sure, all other things being equal. Problem is they never are.

Comment: I conquer with DKNguyan's comment. There is a mix of factors that affecting the top speed of a car. However, without knowing those technical factors, the most straightforward way to figure out is to test drive both cars on the same road in the same environmental conditions. Once on a windy day, once on a calm day, then the difference is most likely due to the efficiency of aerodynamics.  No knowledge of Cd is reqwuired.

Comment: @r13 why conquer his comment? Do you need to beat it?

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/85344/10976

Comment: @SolarMike I need another cup of coffee. I meant to say "I second" or "I agree". Shame on me.

Comment: @r13 "concur" then.

Comment: @SolarMike Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Horsepower and speed do not scale linearly. There are people on the aviation stack exchange that know how to perform scaling comparisons; I suggest you try asking your question there.

Comment: build it, test it.  can do without a number if you have the real thing itself.  That said you can derive it by modeling airflow with other numbers...you do need some properties of the thing you want to model after all.